# How to remove warnings from "keytool" command

Tags: bash, terminal

When I run

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

I get an android debug key hash, but it comes with a warning like this:

> Warning:
>
> The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to
>   migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool
>   -importkeystore -srckeystore /home/racu/.android/debug.keystore -destkeystore /home/racu/.android/debug.keystore -deststoretype pkcs12".
>
> Dswo5LsHyIM+dEniA4dpvwvs7c5=

How can I remove the warning from the output, I'm only interested in printing the very last line:

> Dswo5LsHyIM+dEniA4dpvwvs7c5=

As this is part of a script I use to get all my key hashes.
keytool does not have an `-q`quiet option

Comment: The Warning says what you can do: Migrate to PKCS12. It even gives the full command how to do it. Or, you may to add `2>/dev/null` before the first pipe to  drop stderr.

Comment: Sorry, I think I miss wrote my question, I don't really care about the warning, since it's a debug key. What I want is to remove the warning from the output.

Comment: You got me there, lol :-D
Sorry for not reading it all. I haven't tried yet, but I'm sure you are right.

Comment: Yes, you are totally right, many thanks.